# Ionic 1.x and firebase - having troubles implementing onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm new to `ionic` 1.x and `firebase`, trying to apply the `onAuthStateChanged` method to keep track of the current logged user and auth changes. I am able to register a new user with email and password, able to sign in and sign out, but having troubles implementing `onAuthStateChanged`.
Here's my `services.js` file:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
.service("fireBaseService", function(){

    //sign up
    this.signUp = function(userEmail, password){
      ...
    }

    //sign in
    this.signIn = function(userEmail, password){
     ...
    }

    this.signOut = function(){
    ....
})
.service("authObserver", function(){

    this.auth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log("is logged in");
        } else {
            console.log("signed out!");
            // No user is signed in.
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what the problem is?

Comment: The `onAuthStateChanged` function never get triggered.